# Using task_namespace in luigi produces an error

Tags: python, luigi

I am trying to understand a program that uses luigi to build pipelines.
I have understood the basics but then there is this

```
class Task5(luigi.Task):
    task_namespace = "examples"
    # something else
```

When I comment the line with `task_namespace` the program runs ok but with that line it fails with:

```
luigi.task_register.TaskClassNotFoundException: No task Task5. Did you mean:
Task                                                                 
worker
```

I cannot find a simple example of what `task_namespace` is used. Can someone explain to me how to use this?

Also, What is the "namespace" of a Task?

Comment: what command do you use to run your task?

Comment: `python script.py Task5 --local-scheduler`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer after much research.
task_namespace changes the name of the task. So now if you want to refer to `Task5`, you should refer it as `examples.Task5` because otherwise it would not get recognized. That is why `Task5` was not recognized or found